# ASP.NET Core no HTTPS after publishing to file system and transfer to other machine

Tags: http, asp.net-core, https

Like the title says I publish my ASP.NET Core API to the file system on the PC I developed this application on. If I run this published version HTTPS is working fine. When I transfer the published folder to another machine though, HTTPS is not available anymore. Is there anyone that can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could firstly check the https port is opened or not.

```
 netstat -aon
```

[image]

If you find the 443 port is on using. Then you could check the pid. By using task manager.

[image]

If the process is not IIS or asp.net core process, you could end that process and restart the asp.net core process. Then it will work well.